# QGIS - How can I draw multiple lines [bus route] to be transparent and aesthetic?

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, linestring

PROBLEM: So on this map [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEGcU.jpg) you can observe that there are buses which follows the same route when you zoom in the original resolution after while you can tell which line is which number, but it is not obvious especially for people seeing this for a first time. The lines overlapping themselves. I draw two lines in QGIS [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxxl9.jpg) and as you can see the purple line dominates this navy.

QUESTION: Is there a way to automatize drawing process because I had to draw 2 times route to this red circle on [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxxl9.jpg)? And made the lines stick to their sides (not to overlap) to distinguish colors. Do you have any advice to make this map more clear and transparent?

1:[image: 1]
3:[image: 3]

Comment: I think that Brzozowsky99 is looking for a method to generate a diagram like in this file: https://www.wroclaw.pl/files/komunikacja/schematy/28.06.2014.pdf based on bus routes drawn with one line. I'm curious myself how to do it efficiently in QGIS.

Comment: Can you clarify where you have come so far, it is not fully clear from your post what you have achieved vs. your targeted result. I saw a very nice tutorial explaining how to automatically handle bus maps in qgis, have not been able to find it again so far

Comment: @Kasper I draw few lanes manually and came to conclusion that drawing all 14 bus path will be laborious and not more aesthetic (or worse) than this gimp sketch I posted. I'm looking for a method to set distance between lines to be visible on map, as you can see there are two lines drawn in QGIS and when they are on the same road you can't distinguish them (it's getting even harder when on certain points on the map I have 7 lines next to each other).